# Как удалить репозиторий в GitHub?

Tags: github

Пробовал импортировать репозиторий не получилось. Теперь он "висит" на сайте, но удалить не могу. 
Подскажите, как это сделать.

[image: GH1]

[image: GH2]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заходишь в свой репозиторий - там Settings и в самом низу будет Delete Repository

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот именно, что так нельзя. Когда нажимаешь на sd, переходишь сразу на картинку 2

Comment: @АндрейАртамонов если нажмете Begin Import там Deleta нет?

Comment: Нет, нету(( В принципе получилось, там есть Cancel, откатил, загрузил другой контент и удалил. Спасибо